# Any reason .change event isn't firing when the radio buttons inside table rows are selected?

Tags: jquery, html-table, radio-button

Here is the table

```
<table id="siteTemplateTable" cellpadding="5px">
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="img1.png" width="100" height="100"  alt="Team Site" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="rblSiteTemplates" id="rblSiteTemplates_STS#0" value="STS#0" title="Team Site" />
    </td>
    <td>Team Site 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="img2.png" width="100" height="100"  alt="TS2" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="rblSiteTemplates" id="rblSiteTemplates_STS#1" value="STS#1" title="TS2" /> 
    </td>
    <td>TS2</td>
</tr>
```

jQuery below:

```
        //*********************************************************************
        //toggle the message for site template radion buttons
        //*********************************************************************
        $('input[name="rblSiteTemplates"]').change(function () {
            alert("HERE");
            $("#siteTemplateMessage").hide();
        });
```

The alert never displays and the siteTemplateMessage is never hidden when you select a radio button.  Any thoughts?

siteTemplateMessage is a div on the page.

```
                <div id="siteTemplateMessage" class="template_error_message_indent error_message_pad_top important"></div>
```

The issue is the following.  the user doesn't select a radio button and the `siteTemplateMessage` is `.show()`.  now when they select a radio button the .change event should fire performing the above `.hide()`.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
 $('input[name="rblSiteTemplates"]').click(function () {
```

Comment: no the same behavior, it does NOT hide the siteTemplateMessage div.  i know it has something to do with the radio buttons being inside table rows because i have radio buttons on the same page that work fine with the .change event

Answer (score 0):

.change only gets fired if there is a change, if the radio button is selected and then again the user is clicking on the radio button there is no change so the event is not fired.

If that is the behavior needed then use .click event instead of the .change.

Comment: looking for change, not click.if radio buttons go from no selection to any selection.  they could click the same one multiple times, it doesn't affect the desired behavior.  neither one works, click or change.

Answer (score 0):

your code is almost right. `change` is also working fine. you are `hiding` element with id `siteTemplateMessage` but i dont find any element with such id. i have added an element with this id for testing then i have modified the code . please check fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/qaJXQ/1/

Comment: that does work in fiddler, but it must have something to do with the jquery.wizard and other related plugins.

Comment: nope... everything is available in basic jQuery plugin. There is no much change from your code, few small changes like </table> is missing.